# SQL server 2008 update() function works wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a [table] with a trigger "for update".
There is a statement inside the trigger:

```
if update(field_3)
  begin
    delete from [other_table] where some conditions...
  end
```

When I try to execute

```
update [table] set field_1=1, field_2=2 where key_field=100
```

that "delete" statement inside the trigger works, but I do not update [field_3].
How could it be?

Comment: Are there any other triggers on the table?

Comment: Also, we will probably need to see the whole trigger.

Comment: There's a "known feature" in SQL Server 2008 where an UPDATE() will trigger even if the value doesn't change, but the column is included in the UPDATE statement.  But this doesn't seem to be what is happening here, which seems unlikely?

Comment: `UPDATE` tells you that a column was *potentially* subject to update but doesn't tell you whether any *particular* row's value in that column was *actually* changed. Far better to use `delete from ... from ...` syntax to construct a *set based* delete that applies any necessary logic based on all rows in `inserted` and `deleted` and the actual changes you need to detect.

Comment: There is another trigger on that table - "for delete".

Comment: The whole trigger is big and complex, but I put that "if update(field_3)" in the very top and it works anyway.